# Match regex and assign results in single line of code

Tags: regex, perl

I want to be able to do a regex match on a variable and assign the results to the variable itself. What is the best way to do it?

I want to essentially combine lines 2 and 3 in a single line of code:

```
$variable = "some string";
$variable =~ /(find something).*/;
$variable = $1;
```

Is there a shorter/simpler way to do this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Why do you want it to be shorter? Does is really matter?

```
$variable = $1 if $variable =~ /(find something).*/;
```

If you are worried about the variable name or doing this repeatedly, wrap the thing in a subroutine and forget about it:

```
 some_sub( $variable, qr/pattern/ );
 sub some_sub { $_[0] = $1 if eval { $_[0] =~ m/$_[1]/ }; $1 };
```

However you implement it, the point of the subroutine is to make it reuseable so you give a particular set of lines a short name that stands in their place.

---

Several other answers mention a destructive substitution:

```
( my $new = $variable ) =~ s/pattern/replacement/;
```

I tend to keep the original data around, and [Perl v5.14 has an `/r` flag](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/09/use-the-r-substitution-flag-to-work-on-a-copy/) that leaves the original alone and returns a new string with the replacement (instead of the count of replacements):

```
my $match = $variable =~ s/pattern/replacement/r;
```

Comment: I prefer this answer's use of conditional assignment to the more upvoted answer of `($variable) = $variable =~ /(find).*/` for cases where you explicitly want that conditional assignment if and only if the match works.

Answer (score 63):

```
my($variable) = "some string" =~ /(e\s*str)/;
```

This works because

> If the `/g` option is not used, `m//` in list context returns a list consisting of the subexpressions matched by the parentheses in the pattern, *i.e.*, (`$1`, `$2`, `$3` …).

and because `my($variable) = ...` (note the parentheses around the scalar) supplies list context to the match.

If the pattern fails to match, `$variable` gets the undefined value.

Comment: To add to the description to the list context.  The OoO is equivalent to `my($foo) = ("bar box" =~ /(soap|box)/);`

Comment: I'll also add one other example. If you want to prepend a string to the results in the same call: `my($foo) = map ( "prefix_$_", @{["bar box" =~ /(soap|box)/)]} );`.  You'd end up with "prefix_box" in this case.

Answer (score 7):

You can do substitution as:

```
$a = 'stackoverflow';
$a =~ s/(\w+)overflow/$1/;
```

`$a` is now `"stack"`

Comment: There is a problem with this, It will only replace the original variable if the entire string is present in the search pattern. If I were to use, say, /(\w+)over/ for matching, this wouldn't work.

Comment: The pattern is arbitrary, matches do not necessarily begin or end at a line or word boundary. In any case, thanks, I guess there isn't any obviously simple way to do it. My primary concern was that I have to do this often, and it looks repetitive.

Comment: Stumbled on this 2 year old thread via Google, and I feel this is the correct answer. Just edit the regex to fit your needs: /.*(find something).*/$1/;

Comment: What if you want to have two variables -- the matched pattern and the original

Answer (score 7):

Well, you could say

```
my $variable;
($variable) = ($variable = "find something soon") =~ /(find something).*/;
```

or

```
(my $variable = "find something soon") =~ s/^.*?(find something).*/$1/;
```

Comment: I'd rather use the variable definition separately for clarity's sake, but yes this is a good solution for quick searches. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

From Perl Cookbook 2nd ed
6.1 Copying and Substituting Simultaneously

```pl
$dst = $src;
$dst =~ s/this/that/;
```

becomes

```pl
($dst = $src) =~ s/this/that/;
```

I just assumed everyone did it this way, amazed that no one gave this answer.

Comment: This is substitution (`s///`), not a match (`m//`).  That doesn't make it not useful, but it's why it wasn't among the original answers.

Answer (score 4):

Almost ....

You can combine the match and retrieve the matched value with a substitution.

```
$variable =~ s/.*(find something).*/$1/;
```

AFAIK, You will always have to copy the value though, unless you do not care to clobber the original.

Answer (score 4):

```
$variable2 = "stackoverflow";
(my $variable1) = ($variable2 =~ /stack(\w+)/);
```

`$variable1` now equals `"overflow"`.

Answer (score 3):

I do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$target = "n: 123";
my ($target) = $target =~ /n:\s*(\d+)/g;
print $target; # the var $target now is "123"
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, to amplify the accepted answer using the ternary operator to allow you to specify a default if there is no match:

```
my $match = $variable =~ /(*pattern*).*/ ? $1 : *defaultValue*;
```

Comment: Because this declares `$match`, this expands the most-upvoted answer as well, allowing replacement of `undefined` with `*defaultValue*` in one-line containing the variable declaration.